# add indent witin the quotation box, and make the box continous to multi pages

Tags: latex, quotations

This self-defined quotation box is very beautiful, but there are two problems:

1.It doesn't support the indent
2. the box cannot extend to new pages

Please help to solve it!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\quotebox}[1]
{
  \begin{center}
    \fcolorbox{white}{blue!15!gray!15}{
      \begin{minipage}{0.7\linewidth}\vspace{10pt}
        \center
        \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}{\space\Huge``}{#1}{\hspace{1.5em}\break\null\Huge\hfill''}
        \end{minipage}
        \smallbreak
      \end{minipage}
    }
\end{center}
}

\begin{document}


\quotebox{
Dr. Sung's father was one of those who was blest in 1909. He used to go up on the hill every morning and pray for his family, his church, and for the community. 

He also prayed that God would use his son to bring revival to all China. 

Dr. Sung told me that the name of the town, Hinghwa, was the same sound as the words to bring revival to China.
}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For suporting pagebreaks, use a `tcolorbox instead of your home made box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the `\parindent` to have indention within the `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\quotebox}[1]
{
  \begin{center}
    \fcolorbox{white}{blue!15!gray!15}{
      \begin{minipage}{0.7\linewidth}\vspace{10pt}
        \center
        \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}{\space\Huge``}{\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}#1}{\hspace{1.5em}\break\null\Huge\hfill''}
        \end{minipage}
        \smallbreak
      \end{minipage}
    }
\end{center}
}

\begin{document}


\quotebox{
Dr. Sung's father was one of those who was blest in 1909. He used to go up on the hill every morning and pray for his family, his church, and for the community. 

He also prayed that God would use his son to bring revival to all China. 

Dr. Sung told me that the name of the town, Hinghwa, was the same sound as the words to bring revival to China.
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Really thank you! I just found another problem, the box doesn't extend to the next page, do you have any clue?

Comment: @user13720066 yes, I added a comment. You should not add new questions to your existing post, ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I use `mdframe` to support page breaking! Now it looks better!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcommand{\quotebox}[1]
{
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=red,backgroundcolor=blue!15!gray!15]
   {\space\Huge``}{
     \setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}#1}
   {\hspace{1.5em}\break\null\Huge\hfill''}
\end{mdframed} 
}

\begin{document}


\quotebox{
Dr. Sung's father was one of those who was blest in 1909. He used to go up on the hill every morning and pray for his family, his church, and for the community. 

He also prayed that God would use his son to bring revival to all China. 

Dr. Sung told me that the name of the town, Hinghwa, was the same sound as the words to bring revival to China.
}


\end{document}
```